# Allow file_get_contents null values

Tags: php

Here i have paste the code snippet.Using this code snippet i need to update Database,
If imageName & imageData is not available then upate the db row without those values.
If imageName & imagedata available then update all the vaules.But using this i get the error
All the database fields allow nulls

> Warning: file_get_contents(): Filename cannot be empty in............. line

```
$imageName = mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES["image"]["name"]);

$imageData = mysql_real_escape_string(file_get_contents($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]));

if(empty($imageName)|| ($imageData))  //<-- Not working i think 
{
$sql="UPDATE `news` SET Title ='$Title', Description ='$Des',Category='$Category',ModifiedDate='$DateTime' WHERE id='$id'";
}
else
{
$sql="UPDATE `news` SET Title ='$Title',name='$imageName', Description  ='$Des',Image='$imageData',Category='$Category',ModifiedDate='$DateTime' WHERE id='$id'";
}
```

Comment: The error message isn't about database fields. It's complaining that `$_FILES['image']['tmp_name']` is empty.

Comment: Check the value first.

Comment: Set if( empty($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])) {die("hard");} check before using this variable.. of course this die is just sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change your code to this:

```
if(empty($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]) || !is_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"])) {
$sql="UPDATE `news` SET Title ='$Title', Description ='$Des',Category='$Category',ModifiedDate='$DateTime' WHERE id='$id'";
}
else
{
$imageName = mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]);
$imageData = mysql_real_escape_string(file_get_contents($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]));
$sql="UPDATE `news` SET Title ='$Title',name='$imageName', Description  ='$Des',Image='$imageData',Category='$Category',ModifiedDate='$DateTime' WHERE id='$id'";
}
```